# Small device css are not working as expected in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to show three photo in a row with a container(#field) of full page width in desktop and small devices(tablet). But am not getting three column instead i can able to see only one column for tablets.

but for desktop i can able to see three column same thing applied with a class of `col-sm-*` its not working.

What is the problem here. I'm looking for three column and 25% gap in right as well in left side so i used two column offset in left. Then inside the 8 column i have divided it into 12 as whole and 4 for each so three column will come. But this is not happening in tablet.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49d5Y/)

Between 768px to 991px i believe i should able to see three column, which is `sm` according to the [Document](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) This is not happening in my case.

Why col-sm-* not affecting? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add `col-xs-4` to your div in order to view three columns in small devices.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/49d5Y/1/)**

HTML

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
```

Comment: as they are all 4's you can remove the sm and md ones

Comment: Thanks. am not looking for mobile. I'm looking for three column in tablet which is `sm`

Comment: view the page in a tablet not a jsfiddle it should work

Comment: For mobile how can it become one?. Can it be one column in mobile?

Comment: Thanks same i have viewed mine in responsive design view with firefox tool. But i can't see three column for tablet sizes. Is my code fine? @user1281385